# Plotting issueHighest value shown at the bottom of y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot my dataset, i.e., the number of internship ads, using ggplot, but for some reason, the highest value shows at the bottom of y axis.

Here's the dataset:

```
month       internship_count_2012
January      68
February     48
March        43
April        49
May          52
June         83
July        104
August       91
September    72
October      58
November     70
December     77
```

The image of the plot:

[image]

I've run the following code to come up with the above dataset, which was extracted from a larger, filtered dataset found here: https://www.dropbox.com/home?preview=rwjAll_internship_2012.csv

Filter the dataset by month:

```
rwjAll_internship_jan2012 <- filter(rwjAll_internship_2012, month == 1)
rwjAll_internship_feb2012 <- filter(rwjAll_internship_2012, month == 2)
rwjAll_internship_mar2012 <- filter(rwjAll_internship_2012, month == 3)
rwjAll_internship_apr2012 <- filter(rwjAll_internship_2012, month == 4)
rwjAll_internship_may2012 <- filter(rwjAll_internship_2012, month == 5)
rwjAll_internship_jun2012 <- filter(rwjAll_internship_2012, month == 6)
rwjAll_internship_jul2012 <- filter(rwjAll_internship_2012, month == 7)
rwjAll_internship_aug2012 <- filter(rwjAll_internship_2012, month == 8)
rwjAll_internship_sep2012 <- filter(rwjAll_internship_2012, month == 9)
rwjAll_internship_oct2012 <- filter(rwjAll_internship_2012, month == 10)
rwjAll_internship_nov2012 <- filter(rwjAll_internship_2012, month == 11)
rwjAll_internship_dec2012 <- filter(rwjAll_internship_2012, month == 12)
```

Get the number of internship ads by month

```
jan_2012_internship <- sum(rwjAll_internship_jan2012$internship)
feb_2012_internship <- sum(rwjAll_internship_feb2012$internship)
mar_2012_internship <- sum(rwjAll_internship_mar2012$internship)
apr_2012_internship <- sum(rwjAll_internship_apr2012$internship)
may_2012_internship <- sum(rwjAll_internship_may2012$internship)
jun_2012_internship <- sum(rwjAll_internship_jun2012$internship)
jul_2012_internship <- sum(rwjAll_internship_jul2012$internship)
aug_2012_internship <- sum(rwjAll_internship_aug2012$internship)
sep_2012_internship <- sum(rwjAll_internship_sep2012$internship)
oct_2012_internship <- sum(rwjAll_internship_oct2012$internship)
nov_2012_internship <- sum(rwjAll_internship_nov2012$internship)
dec_2012_internship <- sum(rwjAll_internship_dec2012$internship)
```

Create dataset to plot 2012 internship ads

```
month <- c("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")

internship_count_2012<- c(jan_2012_internship, feb_2012_internship, mar_2012_internship, apr_2012_internship, may_2012_internship, jun_2012_internship, jul_2012_internship, aug_2012_internship, sep_2012_internship, oct_2012_internship, nov_2012_internship, dec_2012_internship)

all_internship_2012 <- cbind(month, internship_count_2012)
all_internship_2012 <- as.data.frame(all_internship_2012)

plot2 <- ggplot(all_internship_2012, aes(x = month, y = internship_count_2012, group = 1)) +
       geom_line(colour="purple1") +
       geom_point(size=0.5, colour="purple1") +
       scale_x_discrete(limits = c("January", "February", "March", "April", "May",                                 "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November",                              "December")) +
       theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

How can I order the y values (internship_count_2012) so that the highest value is at the top? Thanks!

Comment: Your `internship_count_2012` values are stored as factor and not as numeric. Convert them to numeric and then it will work as expected.

Comment: If you `cbind` character strings to numbers, everything gets coerced to strings because `cbind` returns a matrix (which can only have one type). Just use `data.frame` by itself and your problems will go away.

Comment: Also, aim for [DRY code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself); you can use grouping to _significantly_ simplify your code using `aggregate` or it's `dplyr` or `data.table` equivalents.

Comment: Hi Didzis, I used as.numeric() for internship_count_2012 and the numbers were reduced to, and I don't know the reasons why:

January
7

February
3

March
2

April
4

May
5

June
11

July
1

August
12

September
9

October
6

November
8

December
10

Comment: Thanks, alistaire. I'll follow your advice and let you know how it goes.

Comment: You advice, alistaire worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following code simplifies the creation of your new dataset greatly using
the library **dplyr** and produces the plot you desire in just a few lines.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

    all_internship_2012 <- rwjAll_internship_2012 %>%
                           group_by(month) %>%
                           summarise(internship_count_2012 = sum(internship))

    month <- c("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")

    ggplot(all_internship_2012, aes(x = month, y = internship_count_2012)) + 
        geom_line(colour = "purple1") + 
        geom_point(size=0.5, colour="purple1") +
        scale_x_continuous(breaks=1:12, labels = month) +
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

For info about **dplyr** check out [this link on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/databases.html).